# Finding items that are contained in two lists as substrings

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists:

```
var files = new List<string> {"ax_11118.txt", "ax_422226.txt", "ax_4346436.txt", "678678678.txt"};
var codes = new List<string> { "1111", "1234", "5555" };
```

I need to find the items in files which contain this format: "ax_code". The result in this case should be : `{ "ax_11118.txt" }`

I know how to make it with `foreach`, but I was thinking if there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check just code then:

```
files.Where(file => codes.Any(file.Contains));
```

if ax_code:

```
files.Where(file => codes.Any(code => file.Contains($"ax_{code}")));
```

Answer (score 2):

use StartsWith method

```
var files = new List<string> { "ax_11118.txt", "ax_422226.txt", "ax_4346436.txt", "678678678.txt" };
var codes = new List<string> { "1111", "1234", "5555" };
files.Where(file => codes.Exists(code => file.StartsWith($"ax_{code}"))).ToList();
```

Comment: Good idea with StartsWith, it's more optimal solution than mine. +1

Comment: If not in this case , pass the string.Contains function as a delegate is a more beautiful way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var result = files.Where(i => codes.Any(y => i.Contains(y)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Option would be using Join and Custom EqualityComparer

```
var results = files.Join(codes, f=> f, c => c, (f,c) => f,new CustomEqualityComparer());
```

Where CustomEqualityComparer is defined as

```
class CustomEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string left, string right)
    {
        return right.StartsWith($"ax_{left}");
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string str)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```